# Equivalence of ideals of rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Let $R$ be a ring and let $I$ be an ideal in $R$. Prove that the following statements are equivalent.

(1) $I = R$

(2) There exists $u \in R$ such that $u$ is a unit and $u$ belongs to $I$

(3) $1$ belongs to $I$

I only can get that From (1) I know the ring is closed under subtraction and left-right multiplication. And I know I need to prove that equivalent shows that (1) implies (2). Then show (2) implies (3).
Could someone help me to finish it? I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1)\Rightarrow(2)$: take $u=1$.

$(2)\Rightarrow(3)$: let $u\in R$ unit such that $u\in I$. Since $I$ is an ideal we have $1=uu^{-1}\in I$.

$(3)\Rightarrow(1)$: since $I$ is ideal, for all $x\in R$ we have $x=x1\in I$ and so $I=R$.

Comment: could you give me more detailed processes?I can not understand.Thanks

Comment: $(1)\Rightarrow(2)$: Since $I=R$ we have that $1$ is an unit which belongs to $I$.

$(2)\Rightarrow(3)$: Since $I$ is an ideal and $u\in I$ then $ux\in I$ for all $x\in R$. On other hand, $1=uu^{-1}$. So $1=uu^{-1}\in I$.

$(3)\Rightarrow(1)$: Since $I$ is an ideal and $1\in I$, then $x1\in I$ for all $x\in R$. Therefore $x=1x\in I$ for all $x\in R$. Thus we prove that $R\subseteq I$. By definition we know that $I\subseteq R$. So $I=R$.

Comment: Thanks for your explaining.I'd appreciate it!